# AttributeError when adding an item to a basket

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I've been stuck for a while trying to figure why Django throws this `AttributeError` when attempting to add an item to a basket.

**The error looks like this:**
`AttributeError: 'Basket' object has no attribute 'save'`

I've scoured over my code but can't seem to find the issue. I've posted the necessary code below.

**basket/basket.py:**

```
class Basket():
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.session = request.session
        basket = self.session.get('skey')
        if 'skey' not in request.session:
            basket = self.session['skey'] = {}
        self.basket = basket

    def add(self, product, qty):
        """
        Adding and updating the users basket session data
        """
        product_id = str(product.id)

        if product_id in self.basket:
            self.basket[product_id]['qty'] = qty
        else:
            self.basket[product_id] = {'price': str(product.price), 'qty': qty}

        self.save()

    def __iter__(self):
        """
        Collect the product_id in the session data to query the database
        and return products
        """
        product_ids = self.basket.keys()
        products = Product.products.filter(id__in=product_ids)
        basket = self.basket.copy()

        for product in products:
            basket[str(product.id)]['product'] = product

        for item in basket.values():
            item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
            item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['qty']
            yield item

    def __len__(self):
        """
        Get the basket data and count the qty of items
        """
        return sum(item['qty'] for item in self.basket.values())
```

**basket/views.py:**

```
def basket_summary(request):
    basket = Basket(request)
    return render(request, 'main_store/basket/summary.html', {'basket': basket})


def basket_add(request):
    basket = Basket(request)
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
        product_id = int(request.POST.get('productid'))
        product_qty = int(request.POST.get('productqty'))
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
        basket.add(product=product, qty=product_qty)

        basketqty = basket.__len__()
        response = JsonResponse({'qty': basketqty})
        return response
```

**script to add product - single_product.html:**

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '#add-button', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{% url "basket:basket_add" %}',
            data: {
                productid: $('#add-button').val(),
                productqty: $('#select option:selected').text(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{csrf_token}}",
                action: 'post'
            },
            success: function (json) {
                document.getElementById("basket-qty").innerHTML = json.qty
            },
            error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) { }
        });
    })
</script>
```

At first, I thought it may be a simple case of having something named as `basket` instead of the capitalized `Basket`. But I think the issue may be deeper than that.

I'd really appreciate any help and if any more info is needed please let me know and i'll be happy to provide it. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't is as simple as your `Basket` class not having a `save` method but you call it in `Basket.add`?

Comment: Thanks so much, Lain, I knew it had to be an obvious oversight!

Answer (score 1):

The `add` method of your Basket class contains the following line:

> `self.save()`

However, the Basket class currently has no implementation of a method `save`. It doesn't inherit it from any parent class either.

The fact that the `add` method attempts to execute a class method that is undefined explains your attribute error.